# Hoeffding's inequality for general bounded random variables

Tags: probability-theory

In the book [High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) p.18, exercise 2.2.7 is about proving Hoeffding's inequality for general bounded random variables with some absolute constant instead of 2 in the tail. The theorem says: Let $X_1, \dots, X_N$ be independent random variables. Assume that $X_i \in [m_i, M_i]$ for every $i$. Then for any $t>0$, we have:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \mathbb{E}X_i) \geq t \right) \leq \exp \left( - \frac{2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N (M_i - m_i)^2} \right)
$$

We can derive this bound using Hoeffding's lemma and get the constant 2, but this is quite involved and considering the difficulty level of the exercise, there should be a simpler way to get a looser bound for
$$
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda (X - \mathbb{E}X)]
$$
with a different constant.

Any hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some advice: you should type out the exercise explicitly so that people can read it. You also describe things using only words. For example, you say "we can derive the bound using Hoeffding's lemma and get the constant 2," but it's not clear to a reader what the bound is or what your constant 2 is referring to. It's much easier for other people to answer your questions if you include more details.

Comment: Thank you Alan for your feedback, I updated my question.

Comment: Hi, have you found a simpler solution? I had the same thought...